# Stripe: "SessionSubscriptionDataOptions" was not found missing assembly reference visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, stripe-payments

I installed the stripe -Version 34.5.0 for the integration of the payment gateway from my website. Problem is that after installing stripe version 34.5.0, lots of classes are not found which I shared on the attached image.... please check and let me know what is missing? 
[Please go through the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3RZ0.jpg)

Comment: How did you install it? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet

Comment: From the Nuget Package Manager...